# in python when using "range" in for loop for the list (n) , it shows wrong output but without usage of "range" the output is correct,why?

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, range

**1) with "range" in for loop (with wrong output)**

```py
n=[3,5,1,0,2]
even_count, odd_count = 0,0

for i in range(0,len(n)):
    if (i%2==0):
        even_count+=1 
    else:
        odd_count+=1

print("total even nos. are:",even_count)
print("total odd nos. are:",odd_count)
```

Output:

> total even nos. are: **3**
> total odd nos. are: **2**

**2) Without "range" in for loop (with correct output):**

```py
n=[3,5,1,0,2]
even_count, odd_count = 0,0

for i in (n):
    if (i%2==0):
        even_count+=1 
    else:
        odd_count+=1
        
print("total even nos. are:",even_count) 
print("total odd nos. are:",odd_count)
```

Output:

> total even nos. are: **2**
> total odd nos. are: **3**

Comment: `i` has a different meaning in your two samples: index vs list element value.

Comment: In the first example, you are counting how many integers in the range from 0 through 4 are odd or even. If you wanted to check the elements of `n`, you would need t replace `if (i%2==0):` with `if n[i] % 2 == 0:`.

Comment: Try adding `print(i)` to the loop to see what you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

If using `range`, i is the *index*. You can test this by using:

```py
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print(i)
0
1
2
3
4
```

To check if the *number* is even, use `if num[i] % 2 == 0:`

---

Just as a sidenote, your code can be simplified further:

```py
>>> even_count = len([x for x in n if not x % 2])
>>> odd_count = len([x for x in n if x % 2])
>>> even_count, odd_count
(2, 3)
```